# Get item from ng-repeat list using Angular

Tags: html, angularjs

I'm making a project with an list made from a search result. Build like this

```
 <div class="col-lg-6">
    <ul ng-repeat=" wiks in wiki">
       <li ng-mouseenter="abstract = wiks.abstract" ng-mouseleave="abstract = ''">
       <a href="#/view2">{{wiks.title}}</a>
       </li>
            <p>{{abstract}}</p>
   </ul>
 </div>
```

The wiks object has more than just the title and abstract in it. To reduce the amount of calls to the server I'd really like to save this object in a variable in my controller for the next view.

```
.controller('View1Ctrl',['$scope','WikiFactory' , function($scope, WikiFactory) {
    $scope.title = "Wiki Search Site";
    $scope.search = "";
    $scope.wiki= "";

    $scope.getWiki= function getWiki() {
        WikiFactory.getWiki($scope.search)
            .success(function (wiki) {
                $scope.wiki = wiki;
            })}
}])

.controller('wikiController', ['$scope','WikiFactory', function($scope , $WikiFactory){

    }])
```

So I've tried to make a $scope.specifiedWik in my View1Ctrl but cant seem to find out how to get it to be the wiks that I click on. When this problem is solved I wonder wether or not it is ok by "the big book og programming law" just to call a $scope.wiki = $scope.$parent.specifikWiki in the new controller?

Thanks if anybody can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would store the object in your factory so it is available to other controller(s).

```
<li ng-click="selectWiki(wiks)">
```

In controller:

```
$scope.selectWiki = function(wiki){
   WikiFactory.selected = wiki;
}
```

Now when other controller loads you can do something like:

```
$scope.selected = WikiFactory.selected;
```

Comment: actully this is even greater thanks alot.. Both could have been used

Answer (score 0):

You will need the `$index` of item from `ng-repeat`

```
<ul ng-repeat="wiks in wiki">
   <li ng-click="showOneWiki($index)" 
       ng-mouseenter="abstract = wiks.abstract" 
       ng-mouseleave="abstract = ''">
         <a href="#/view2">{{wiks.title}}</a>
   </li>
        <p>{{abstract}}</p>
</ul>
```

now you ca use this `showOneWiki($index)` function to get the clicked wiki

```
.controller('View1Ctrl',['$scope','WikiFactory' , function($scope, WikiFactory) {
$scope.title = "Wiki Search Site";
$scope.search = "";
$scope.wiki= "";
$scope.specifiedWik = {}; //to hold current wiki

//This will hold the current wiki
$scope.showOneWiki = function(index) {
  $scope.specifiedWik = $scope.wiki[index];
}

$scope.getWiki= function getWiki() {
    WikiFactory.getWiki($scope.search)
        .success(function (wiki) {
            $scope.wiki = wiki;
         })}
}])
```

$index will returned current clicked item index in array